# Searching and clearing LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, browser, local-storage

I know, localStorage supports up to 5MB only. In our application we are planning use localStorage (sessionStorage doesn't fits for our need, since we support multiple tabs). Currently there is only one big javascript object serialized and stored in localStorage, in the future it may exceed up to 15 objects but definitely not more than that.

The problem is, clearing the localStorage. Since our application allows user to login in multiple ways (SSO etc...). So without landing in Login page, they can login into our application and as well as signing off in other application will sign off in our application too or close the browser. For security reason, we need to clean the localStorage once the user session is over.

So we planned to store the personId in localStorage, in every page request along with the html response we send the personId from the server, and if it doesn't match with the localStorage's personId then it will clear the localStorage.

My doubt here is, search in localStorage is not asynchronous so will it take much time to search personId out of 15 keys (Which has some large string as value)?

```
localStorage.setItem("personId", 1234);
localStorage.setItem("object1", "A very big serialized form of javascript object gets stored");
```

Comment: You mean, when user clicks logout? Because there's no way you can react to session over.

Comment: what if the user closes the browser instead clicking Logout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing values is really fast and there is no significant difference between large and short values: http://jsperf.com/local-storage-set

You can test the search on this site too... You could share the search code too, so others can take a look on it.